# Ways of encapsulating choice of Java primitive; Avoiding "magic" primitives

Tags: java, coding-style, primitive, primitive-types

I'm writing a program which creates a large number of large arrays to store data. All of this data has to held in RAM, so I'm avoiding objects and currently using shorts to save space. These shorts serve as ID numbers which can be put into a lookup class to get the corresponding object on demand. I have recently questioned whether I'll need the whole 2 bytes of a short, and so I'm now wondering if there's anyway to define the data type being stored in one place in my code so that I can change it easily without having to hunt down every cast, return type, etc. that is currently set to short.

If I were willing to use objects I could easily just do

```
class MySmallNumber extends Short{}
```

and change the parent class if necessary.

If this were C/C++, i could use

```
#define small short
```

for the effect I'm looking for.

I'm searching for a way to do something like this in java that won't require storing 64-bit object references in my arrays. Any help is greatly appreciated. Right now I'm looking at a really messy IDE replace all in order to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c)

Comment: "_I could easily just do_ `class MySmallNumber extends Short{}`" -- no you couldn't because `Short` is `final`.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I think the answers to the other question essentially cover this one as well.  Basically, no way to do this for primitives in Java.

Comment: Have you considered an alternative solution of building a class which acts as a container to your large array of `whatever`s, and building simple get-/setter methods into it?  You could avoid casting (outside of the class) by defining get-/setters explicitly for each type, e.g., `.getByte(int index)`, `.getShort(int index)`.  This hides your implementation (which appears to be your overarching goal) and minimizes container classes.

Comment: Small question: is under 32K of objects such a big number? I'm pretty sure 32K references don't take *that* much space; that's on a reasonably new computer anyway.

Comment: @owlstead If the question is "Are references really too big?" (I'm not sure I'm reading your comment correctly), the answer is that it makes the difference between the program using 300-500 MB of RAM and using 4 times that amount. Many computers have the space, but it wouldn't be polite of me as a programmer to use that RAM if I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest factoring out all code that depends on the type of your ID values into a separate class. Let that class handle all the operations (including lookup) that depend on whether the ID values are `short`, `byte`, or something else. You can pass individual values in and out as `short` or even `int` values, even if internally they are converted to `byte`. (This is, for instance, how `java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(int)` was written—it takes an `int` argument and treats it as a `byte` value.)

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation. I got fixated on using the actual stored data types everywhere in the code, but this is clearly the right way to handle things.

Answer (score 2):

You can incapsulate you array in some custom class. It shouldn't add considerable space overhead because you work with **large** arrays.

In all other places in your code you can use long. When you pass these longs to you array custom class you can convert it to the one you use inside it.

Finally you have to make changes in this one class only.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you are after here, but this may be of interest:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
interface Index {
    short getIndex(int i);
    void setIndex(int i, short value);
    int size();
}
class ShortIndexImpl implements Index {
    ShortIndexImpl(int n) {
        indices = new short[n];
    }
    @Override public short getIndex(int i) {
        return indices[i];
    }
    @Override public void setIndex(int i, short value) {
        indices[i] = value;
    }
    @Override public int size() {
        return indices.length;
    }
    final short[] indices;
}
class TenBitIndexImpl implements Index {
    TenBitIndexImpl(int n) {
        indices = new int[(n + 2) / 3];
    }
    @Override public short getIndex(int i) {
        int index = i / 3;
        int remainder = i % 3;
        int word = indices[index];
        return (short) (0x3ff & (word >> shifts[remainder]));
    }
    @Override public void setIndex(int i, short value) {
        int index = i / 3;
        int remainder = i % 3;
        int word = indices[index] & ~masks[remainder];
        int shiftedValue = ((int) value) << shifts[remainder];
        word |= shiftedValue;
        indices[index] = word;
    }
    @Override public int size() {
        return indices.length;
    }
    final int masks[] = new int[] { 0x3ff00000, 0xffc00, 0x3ff };
    final int shifts[] = new int[] { 20, 10, 0 };
    final int[] indices;
}
public class Main {
    static void test(Index index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            index.setIndex(i, values[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(values[i] + " " + index.getIndex(i));
            if (index.getIndex(i) != values[i])
                System.out.println("expected " + values[i] + " but got " + index.getIndex(i));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Index index = new ShortIndexImpl(values.length);
        test(index);
        index = new TenBitIndexImpl(values.length);
        test(index);
        System.out.println("indices");
        for (int i = 0; i < ((TenBitIndexImpl) index).indices.length; i++)
            System.out.println(((TenBitIndexImpl) index).indices[i]);
    }
    static short[] values = new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
}
```