# Simulating C++-typedefs in Java

Tags: java, c++, generics, introspection

Can `typedef FooBar Bar;` and the access to the type FooBar through the expression `Foo::Bar` in the code

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class FooBar {};
class FooBat {};

class Foo
{
public:
    typedef FooBar Bar;
    typedef FooBat Bat;
};

int main()
{
    if( typeid(Foo::Bar) == typeid(FooBar) && 
        typeid(Foo::Bat) == typeid(FooBat) )
        std::cout << "All is well." << std::endl;
}
```

be translated to Java?

What would be the Java equivalent for an indirect reference to a type?

The STL and boost are filled with code such as

```
typedef T              value_type;
typedef T*             iterator;
```

and I am wondering whether Java supports a similar generic programming idiom.
I am still interested in an answer even if the type indirection cannot be done at compile time.

**Edit**
The question (how to do nontrivial generic programming in Java) is not getting any interest from those conversant in Java. I am now adding "C++" as a tag.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ program in the question translates to the following Java code:

```
public class FooBat {}
public class FooBar {}

public class Foo {
    public static Class get_Bar() { return FooBar.class; }
    public static Class get_Bat() { return FooBat.class; }
}

public class Introspect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if( Foo.get_Bar() == FooBar.class &&
            Foo.get_Bat() == FooBat.class )
            System.out.println( "All is well.\n" );
    }
}
```

This is not as efficient as the C++ code. The types are determined in the C++ version during compilation. In the Java version they are determined at run-time.

A better answer that remedies this issue is most welcome.

Comment: Say you are implementing a graph class. You want it to be parameterized by a vertex and an edge, but you don't want just any pair of classes to be allowed. So you write a class (such as Foo) that acts as graph traits. Bar and Bat are the generic vertex and edge. In place of Introspect, we would have a (rather longer) class that uses the two actual classes FooBat and FooBar.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare classes with:

```
Object a = . . .;
Object b = . . .;
if (a.getClass().equals(b.getClass())) {
    // a and b are instances of the same class
}
if (a.getClass().isAssignableFrom(b.getClass())) {
    // the class of a is a superclass of b's class
}
```

However, Java does not have anything like `typedef` that allows you to use one type name as an alias for another.

Comment: The methods get_bar() and get_bat() are an example of how I am hoping Java can facilitate generic programming. Could you look at the class Foo and critique it?