# How can I change variable type names in Java using NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am so used to C++ & C# where I can type bool. In Java, I am required to type boolean. Also, it requires me to type String with uppercase 'S'. I would love to be able to create project wide aliases for these variable types to enable me to create variables by typing bool and string. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Java does not have a preprocessor. Please don't write C++ in Java, they're different languages.

Comment: What you are describing is impossible within the limits of the Java language. I'm unfamiliar with Netbeans, but I find it incredibly unlikely that this feature exists.

Comment: As you followed syntax in C++&C#, you have to follow Java syntax accordingly, No more choices

Comment: I think there is no answer for this question

Comment: If your question is about Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++? [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's impossible to write C++ in Java. I was just looking for help in ensuring that I use Java properly.

Comment: I've seen people write COBOL in Java. For example, you could create a class `string` that extends `String`... but please do not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I see now that it is the nature of Java not to have aliases, but Kevin's idea answered my question perfectly. I would imagine that Java has made the String class final to keep people from doing that. I can only imagine the horror stories of people who have used Java for years.

Comment: You must have seen some of the abusive things you can do with a pre-processor macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to actually change the syntax of the language, that is not only impossible, but a terrible idea. Aliases would make code indecipherable to others.

However, it is possible to only type `'bool'+{TAB}` and `'string'+{TAB}` and have NetBeans change it to `'boolean'` or `'String'`, respectively. In fact, you have much more flexibility than that (for example, you could make it `'boo'+{SPACE}='boolean'` or `'bo'+{ENTER}='boolean')`.

Take a look at `'NetBeans->Preferences->Editor->Code Templates'` if that is the kind of thing you need; should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: That's very cool. I made it 'bool'+{SPACE}='boolean' and 'string'+{SPACE}='String'. This is going to save me so many build errors. Thank you.