# Typedef in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I define type in Scala?
Like

```
type MySparseVector = [(Int, Double)]
```

in Haskell or

```
typedef MySparseVector = std::list<std::pair(int, double)>>
```

in C++?

I tried

```
type MySparseVector = List((Int, Double))
```

but can't figure how to make it work. If I write this in the beginning of class file I got "Expected class or object definition" error.

PS Sorry, I mistyped. I tried to use List[(Int, Double)] in Scala.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
type MySparseVector = List[(Int, Double)]
```

Example usage:

```
val l: MySparseVector = List((1, 1.1), (2, 2.2))
```

Types have to be defined inside of a class or an object. You can import them afterwards. You can also define them within a package object - no import is required in the same package, and you can still import them into other packages. Example:

```
// file: mypackage.scala
package object mypackage {
  type MySparseVector = List[(Int, Double)]
}

//in the same directory:
package mypackage
// no import required
class Something {
  val l: MySparseVector = Nil
}

// in some other directory and package:
package otherpackage
import mypackage._
class SomethingElse {
  val l: MySparseVector = Nil
}
```

Comment: where can I define this? Before any class definition?

Comment: The trick in Scala is that typedefs (like variable and method definitions, can't live at the top level.  They need to be inside a class or object.  The usual practice is to include them in an object, and then import the object's contents where you need the typedef.  This gives you control over just where the typedef is used, and prevents name collisions.

Comment: It has to be inside a class or object

Comment: Inside a class or object, and not a trait (as I've spent 5 mins discovering!)