# Possible ways to create "typedef" in Java

Tags: java, c++, typedef

I have some horrible classes' names. And I need to rename them, to make them more human-readable.

In **C/C++**, it is possible to create **typedef**, it resolves the problem.

But what about in **Java**? What are the possible ways to do it?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: `In C/C++, it is possible to create typedef, it resolves the problem.` - I would say it does not solve it, but rather hides it. Use a tool like Eclipse to refactor your code instead.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c

Comment: Refactoring isn't always a solution. Imagine if you have third-party code that you're not allowed to change.

Comment: @jia103 If your third party vendor delivers an API which consists of `horrible class names` you should consider changing the vendor ;) Seriously, in that case I would prefer to wrap the library with a facade

Comment: That might be the only solution. Of course, you could always use #define macros and run the file through a C preprocessor if you're **really** adamant. (Oops...was that out loud?)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any aliasing mechanisms in Java. Probably because aliasing drastically disminishes readability, as you may see a block of code and don't have any idea of what the types really are.

Comment: Conversely MISRA requires C/C++ programs to use typedef'ed sized types instead of basic types

Comment: That's for a completely different reason than here. The sizes of types is not defined by any standard, so if you always need a 16-bit unsigned integer or a 32-bit signed integer, you need to call out something in your code to explicitly state something like `UINT16` or `SINT32`, respectively. In this case, you're not changing a class named `OneDimensionalArray` to `MyVector` just for the sake of name changing.