# In Java, how to rewrite smthing like "typedef double Scalar"?

Tags: java, typedef

I am fairly new to Java. I used to work with C++. For one task, my Java code needs to be flexible enough for a performance test with float and double. In C++, I can simply write my code with "typedef float Scalar", and use Scalar as my primitive type across the code. When changing to double, I could replace that line with  "typedef double Scalar". How could I do similar thing in Java?

I read [Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c) . Someone mentioned a pseudo-typedef, but I think that doesn't apply to my case, as I try to typedef a primitive type. Any suggestion?

Very appreciated.

Comment: I think that Generics might provide what you are looking for, although not applicable for primitive types. You can define a class or method with Generics, and then use the same class with different types e.g Integer or Float

Comment: Each of the primitive types in Java has an object type that can be used like it in most situations, i.e. int->Integer, float->Float. I still wouldn't recommend using the pseudo-typedefing as it makes for fairly unmaintainable Java code.
@CocoNess: generics can be used with the Integer,Float, etc. types and then used with the primitives

Comment: The 'pseudo-typedef' you talk about was mentioned as an anti-pattern (a bad practice), if you want to typedef, Java is not the language you're should be using, sorry

Comment: Thanks all for replying! I think too Generics is a solution. However, as the code base is very large, it is awkward to make all involved classes Generic. Maybe my question should be rephrased as "how do I make a large codebase be toggable between float and double computation (the simplest way)?"

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't really have anything similar to `typedef`. I think the closest you could get would be to define a `Scalar` class to wrap a `float` or `double`, but then you wouldn't be able to conveniently use operators such as `+` and `-` (and it might just be overkill to do so in general).