# ADT, typedef and representation independence in Java

Tags: java, adt, guava, typedef

I would like to define an ADT that has the same interface as a java.util.Map.
However I read that it is an anti-pattern to make it MyType extends Map as explained here:
[Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c?lq=1)

Since in Java there is no equivalent to the C/C++ typedef there is no way to define a true type synonym.

I am thinking about these 2 solutions:

- Define a concrete wrapper/forwarding class for java.util.Map, but this would force me to code against a class instead of coding against an interface. I was looking at Guava's ForwardingMap but this is a class and not an interface.
- Define my own interface which mimics java.util.Map and an implementation that wraps a java.util.Map.  I don't like this duplication but I don't see any workaround that gives me the benefits of being able to program against an interface and representation independence.

Would it make sense to write something like `public interface MyType<K,V> extends Map<K,V>` and then:

```
public class MyTypeImpl<K, V> extends ForwardingMap<K, V> implements MyType<K, V> {

    final Map<K, V> delegate;

    public MyTypeImpl() {
        this(new HashMap<K, V>());
    }

    public MyTypeImpl(Map<K, V> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<K, V> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Aren't you decorating HashMap?

Comment: If the interface is identical to Map, why don't you use Map? What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: @almas shaikh: I am not adding any new runtime behavior to a Map for now. At a higher level I want to define an ADT for an associative data structure to represent a generic Data Transfer Object and I find the Map interface has all I need.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I want to define an ADT to achieve representation independence (define my type in terms of the operations provided by the Map interface) so I can later change it without hunting for explicit references to Map.

Comment: Then your second solution is what you need. The implementation you suggest is an easy one, unless you're concerned that users keep referring to your ADT as Map rather than MyType (as in `Map<K, V> map = new MyTypeImpl<>()`).

Comment: @JB Nizet: that would be ugly.  So it seems like if I want to completely hide my representation there is no solution but to duplicate the Map interface.