# Why would a map helper extending hashmap be useful? Why not just use hashmap?

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrenthashmap

In a large java code base in my recent job, I see the below code:

```
public class MapHelper extends HashMap<String, Object>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MapHelper() {
        super();
    }

    public MapHelper(MapHelper mh) {
        super(mh);
    }

    public MapHelper as_dict(String key) {
        return (MapHelper)this.get(key);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how this would be useful. Are there examples you have that could shed light on the above MapHelper's usefulness?

Comment: Check VCS and ask the author.

Comment: The mistake you make is in assuming that code you inherit must be useful or have a reason for existing.

Comment: looks like it's been done to save the client from casting HashMap values from Object to MapHelper, but need more context to really know so I agree with @Markus Malkusch

Comment: It wouldn't. This class appears to be completely pointless. All it does is add one method of questionable utility.

Comment: Side-note: If you haven't already, review your company's policy on posting code from your project's codebase online. Even small snippets like this can get you into trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class *does* seem relatively frivolous the way it is now; however:

1. It lets them refer to `HashMap<String, Object>` as `MapHelper` which is shorter and guarantees consistency. See also [*'Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?'*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195242/2891664).
2. `as_dict` is a utility method that performs a cast. They appear to have foresight about what the Map contains. This *is* safer than doing the cast inline because the cast is defined in only one place. Less margin for error.
3. It lets them add additional functionality later without having to update the entire code-base.
4. Extending `HashMap` as a top-level class makes the generic type arguments reified, that is, they are available at runtime through reflection. See [this blog post by Neal Gafter](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) that explains this feature in more detail.

So there are actually quite a few small but legitimate reasons to do this.

There are some examples like this in the Java API such as:

- [`Properties extends Hashtable<Object, Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)
- [`UIDefaults extends Hashtable<Object, Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html)

Comment: I also outlined point 4, but it is not really a good argument, since you would not need reflection, cause you already know, that it's <String, Object> cause the class is compiled like that.

Comment: @dognose I agree it seems unlikely they are actually using this feature but it's still one of the reasons this can be done.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the only purpose of this class is *having a shortcut*.

Instead of doing

```
Map<String, Map<String,  Map<String,  Map<String, Object>>>> myMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,  HashMap<String,  HashMap<String, Object>>>>();
```

(which is bad to read)

you could use

```
MapHelper myHelper = new MapHelper(new MapHelper(new MapHelper(new MapHelper())));
```

since `MapHelper` will exactly limit the generic type attributes to be `String` and `Object`

Finally imagine, you want to check if ANY element equals "1" while not knowing the depth - You could call a recursive method over and over again - or implement it **once** on the MapHelper.

```
if (myHelper.contains("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the class is to prevent you from having to hardcode `HashMap<String, Object>` every place you want to use that type of map (it increases abstraction). By extending it into MapHelper, you reduce repetition and it prevents you from having to clutter your code with the diamond operator.

A better name for the class would be something that describes what the underlying map types are (without being too specific):

```
public class StringMapHelper extends HashMap<String, Object>
```

If you do it that way, the class name is still descriptive even if you end up changing the key datatype, and again, you don't have to replace the key type everywhere in your code:

```
public class StringMapHelper extends HashMap<FancyString, Object>
```